# USB type-c power supply (up to 20V 5A) from DC source

Tags: power-supply, charger, usb-c

I have a custom made 5s power bank (30 x 18650 cells) and I want to make a power supply to charge my laptop using this power bank. It's not a big deal to make a 5V charger because I just have to hard wire a 5V step down regulator and it will work, but what about higher voltages?

Of course, I can use a standard AC power supply and connect it using a car power inverter, but efficiency in this case will be quite low. I tried to find such power supply/controller on aliexpress or ebay, but it looks like only 5V versions are available. What is the best/easiest way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: boost converters work the same as bucks, what the question?

Comment: `but what about higher voltages?` is a bit ambiguous. Please ask more direct questions. Forget Ebay, they are a parts broker, not a supplier. Use the search terms "buck regulator" and "boost regulator" and you will find plenty of vendors.

Comment: Which "Power Delivery over Type-C design" guidances did you digest before asking this question?

Comment: @Sparky256 i mean pd over usb-c

Comment: As it turns out, this appears to be a shopping question. It should be closed as "off topic".

Comment: How is this a shopping question? If you read into it it doesn't look like a shopping question to me. "What is the best way to do it?" and the question about step down regulators doesn't look like shopping

Comment: @laptop2d, because the OP said later, actually, "I wanted to buy one, but..". Full explanation on how to make a PD adapter was given in my answer, with all necessary references etc., and it was accepted.  Half-year later someone found a off-the shelf adapter (which didn't exist at the time of original question), and OP changed his mind and re-voted his acceptance to the "shopping answer". Which renders the question as "shopping". Just pulling strings a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware of two such devices.

1. ChargerLAB POWER-Z DC to USB PD Converter Board JGL-DCPD review at https://kknews.cc/digital/e8mezky.html
2. Magicfox PD180. It takes a 12-28V DC via 5.5 * 2.5/2.1mm barrel (or USB C PD 100W) and provides two USB C ports and an USB A port. A review  http://bbs.chongdiantou.com/thread-57387-1-1.html here and the same is https://kknews.cc/zh-tw/digital/rorpmmv.html here as well.

Google Translate helps in translating the Chinese reviews. The first one seems to be available from an Asian reseller in English, shipping worldwide (Google is your friend). The second is on jd.com but there are various Chinese shopping proxies to help.

Comment: This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @chx: I am looking for such a USB PD-source which accepts 5V input. Does not seem to be any out there, right? The ChargerLAB POWER-Z DC to USB PD Converter Board JGL-DCPD seems to take 8..36V input.

Answer (score 3):

Form the set of keywords "USB", "type-C", "power supply" "up to 20V 5A" and the literal question,

> I want to make a power supply to charge my laptop using this power
>   bank. It's not a big deal to make a 5V charger ...[snip], but what
>   about higher voltages?

it is obvious the that the question is about [implementation of Power Delivery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/361401/117785) protocol over Type-C CC lines and design of power supply (controllable DC-DC converter) with variable output in accord with Power Delivery handshake protocol.

Answer: there are several semiconductor companies who offer a portfolio of ICs and design guidances on how to build a PD over Type-C.

One is Texas Instruments, see [their presentation](http://www.usb.org/developers/presentations/USB_DevDays_Taipei_2017_Designing_USB_Type-C_PD_Systems.pdf) on USB Developer Days 2017.

The other is ST Micro, [see their guide](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group0/5a/b1/8e/6c/2b/0d/46/3c/Apec/files/APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf).

Cypress Semiconductors offers a portfolio of [reference designs](http://www.cypress.com/products/usb-type-c-and-power-delivery#tabs-0-bottom_side-6) as well.

This is from just the first page of Google search. There are several other companies like Maxim, Fairchild, NXP, ON Semi, Renesas/NEC, Rohm, and maybe many more Chinese sources with similar products.

Comment: thank you for you answer, I tried to google it and I have some understanding how pd over usb-c works, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, i.e. I expected there should be ootb solutions. I found several such devices, but they're not power enough.

Comment: @Tutankhamen, what do you mean "not power enough"? One standard design approach is to have several DC-DC converters, at least two, one for +5Vsafe default, and the other one for the profile you plan to offer (like 20V 5A), and then program your PD receiver in accord with your profile. When the profile is accepted by device, you just switch to +20V using a good switch. But you have to make the power option by yourself, so there is no such thing as "not power enough", it is up to you, and 20V5A unit is certainly doable.

Comment: Yes, 20V 5A is exactly what I need, I said I found several ootb devices which provides maximum 3Amps. Like this one https://www.amazon.com/BiXPower-Type-Power-Converter-Delivery/dp/B07BC5TWJB and it's not enough for me

Comment: @Tutankhamen, then I misunderstood you, I thought you want to make your own Type-C Power delivery supply, not to buy one.

Comment: actually, I wanted to buy one, but if it's impossible, then try build it. May be it is a good idea to try to build one. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution, I found a DC to PowerDelivery converter which has reviews on Amazon. I have not used this myself I a searching for a Solar Panel DC output to PowerDelivery converter. I may eventually try this myself, but none of the reviews talked about solar panels, just AC power supplies with this device. [https://www.amazon.com/BiXPower-Type-Power-Converter-Delivery/dp/B07BC5TWJB/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=USB+Type+C+Power+Converter+bixpower&qid=1581808832&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BC5TWJB)
I thought power delivery devices would be more prevalent now, but only a few solar panels with PD output are available which are very expensive.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We generally don't do product recommendations as they quickly become obsolete as will the links in your answer and your post will be useless then. You might enjoy the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) which explains how the site works.