# Integrating USB C Power Delivery into a PCB

Tags: power-supply, usb, pcb-design, programming

I am aware of USB C Power Delivery trigger boards that uses PD protocol to output the desired voltage from a PD source. But I was curious if it would be possible and feasible to design and integrate a USB C Power Delivery protocol into a PCB design. If I were to do it, how difficult would it be and what would I need to know? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it would be feasible, since the boards you have do it.  You could buy the same USB-PD controller IC and put it on your board, or use one of various designs online.

Comment: It's complicated; think a whole engineering project's worth. Start with https://www.google.com/search?q=implementing+usb+power+delivery and choose someone's docs to read and parts to consider.

Comment: You would likely want to use a USB-PD IC plus a micro-controller with a library to support that particular chip. Suggest you look for an eval board to start.

Comment: With modern ic chips, this is not a hard problem to solve...

Comment: You need to integrate the "power delivery trigger board" electronics into your PCB project. All answers/variants are given here, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/361391/117785